# Converting IEEE single precision to decimal

Tags: floating-point, single-precision

If S = 0, E = 01110011, and F = 100101

E would be 115 right? and if so would that make the exponent -12 ?

If the Bias is 127.

Comment: 115 - 127 = -12. But that is 2^-12.

Comment: If you can, can you explain how I can get the scientific notation from the S, E, and F?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how your number parses as a 32-bit SP IEEE-754 float:

```
                  3  2          1         0
                  1 09876543 21098765432109876543210
                  S ---E8--- ----------F23----------
          Binary: 0 01110011 10010100000000000000000
             Hex: 39CA 0000
       Precision: SP
            Sign: Positive
        Exponent: -12 (Stored: 115, Bias: 127)
       Hex-float: +0x1.94p-12
           Value: +3.8528442e-4 (NORMAL)
```

The stored exponent is `115`, which coresponds to `-12` with a bias of `127`.